# gooey effect with react-native

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-native, svg-filters

Is possible to implement this effect in react native ?

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/03/10/creative-gooey-effects/

As I read this effect is based on svg filters that currently are not supported in react native. Any alternative than usign svg filters that is possible in react native?

Comment: Well those filter effects are available through Core Image on Apple platforms, but you'd have to build a native module to access those classes.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution regarding this?